# How make more advanced charts in node-red? How can I make live chart in Node-red with two or more y axis?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, dashboard, node-red

I have problem with make more advanced live chart. I use node-red on PC to collect data from PLC and display it in line chart using standard node-red dashboard chart node. PLC read values from 30 sensors: 20 preassure, 3 temperature, 3 flow, 1 speed. Read frequency is 4Hz. Not all values are visible at time, because I want chart to be clear. For this I need also split y axis according to sensors. So one for preassure, one for temperature, one for flow and one for speed. For now data is coming in form of array msg.payload[] but it is not important because I will  format data to proper form. I know format data for live chart to work is

```
{topic:"temperature", payload:22}
{topic:"humidity", payload:66}
```

and for static chart

```
msg.payload =[{
"series": ["A", "B", "C"],
"data": [
    [{ "x": 1504029632890, "y": 5 },
     { "x": 1504029636001, "y": 4 },
     { "x": 1504029638656, "y": 2 }
    ],
    [{ "x": 1504029633514, "y": 6 },
     { "x": 1504029636622, "y": 7 },
     { "x": 1504029639539, "y": 6 }
    ],
    [{ "x": 1504029634400, "y": 7 },
     { "x": 1504029637959, "y": 7 },
     { "x": 1504029640317, "y": 7 }
    ]
],
"labels": [""]
}]
```

.
[standard chart with data from above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6IXd.png)
I know node-red dashboard chart is similar to chart.js. I can send ui_control message to adjust actual y-axe and add two more y-axis:

```
let msg2=
{
    ui_control :{ 
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'minute',
                        unitStepSize: 1,
                        displayFormats: {
                            minute: 'HH:mm'
                        }
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    id: "1",
                    scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'pressure [bar]'
                            },
                    ticks: {
                        min: -10,
                        max: 10,
                        stepSize: 2
                    }
                }, {
                    id: "2",
                    scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Temperature [°C]'
                            },
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 20,
                        stepSize: 4
                    }
                    }, {
                    id: "3",
                    scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Flow [L/min]'
                            },
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 20,
                        stepSize: 4
                    }
                }]
            }    ,        
                legend: {
                    display: true,
        position: 'top',
      },
      
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart'
      }
    ,
            animation: {
                duration: 0
            }
        }},
};

return msg2;
```

Result is:
[Same data, ui_control message result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ9Fd.png)

And now I want display for example:

```
msg.payload = 5;
msg.topic="C";
msg.yAxis="3";
return msg;
```

and instead get "C" on axe 3 (temperature), I get it on axe 1 (pressure), and Node-red sometimes freeze after send above message.
[chart with one data point on 1 y axe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uWyP.png)

So now proper question: How Can I use more than one y axis? Can I done this with standard node-red dashboard chart? How data structure should look for static chart, and how for live chart? Maybe I should use node-red template node and write code in HTML based on chart.js? And one last question, how can I minimalize PC usage, because when I run 30 sensors, at 4Hz, I get 1200 point in just 10s?

I will be grateful for your help :D

Comment: looks like you want to solve what grafana does. maybe worthy too look around what for examples where node red uses influx/ grafana

Answer (score 1):

After while I found best solution for me. I made flow and make it public for everyone: https://flows.nodered.org/flow/138cbddaf5ecda8f36cf4dcd1bcf9d5d
Grafana with influx is best for historical data. For real time data (refresh 4Hz) Grafana is to heavy. In my solution I used chart.js, luxon, luxon adapter for chart.js and chartjs-plugin-streaming implemented in Node-Red. With this I can make chart with multiline, multi axis with full trend configuration. This work fine
[image: my chart]